# Получить событие из виртуальной клавиатуры

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть скрипт поисковика, вводимые слова из обычной клавиатуры работают как надо, вводится слово, а из вводимого окна подсказка, если эту же процедуру проходить из виртуальной клавиатуры, то подсказки не выводятся.

```
**// форма поисковой системы**
<form action="" method="get">
        <ul class="search">
            <textarea rows="1" wrap="off" id="autocomplete" class="search" name="search"></textarea>
<input type="submit" class="search-go" name="go-search" value="пошук"  />
        </ul>
    </form>

    **//Виртуальная клавиатура**
     <div id="keyboard">
        <li class="letter">й</li>
        <li class="letter">ц</li>
        <li class="letter">у</li>
        /////// и так далее///////
        </div>

            **//событие на вывод подсказки**
                $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
                        source: path +'search.php',
                        minLength: 1,
                        select: function( event, ui){
                        window.location = path + 'index-ru.php?search=' + encodeURIComponent(ui.item.value);
                        }
                    });
                    });
```

Как надо описать событие, чтобы оно реагировало на виртуальную клавиатуру?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li.letter').mouseup(function(e){
$('#autocomplete').val($('#autocomplete').val()+$(this).text()).autocomplete("search",$('#autocomplete').val());
});
```